# How to clone a file descriptor? (not just duplicate it)

Tags: c, posix, nonblocking, file-descriptor

I want to clone a file descriptor. So that changing it with `fcntl()` does not change the original file descriptor.

Reopening the same path does not work in my case, the file descriptor may point to a pipe or socket.

### Background:

I want to read from an inherited file descriptor without blocking. But when i enable the flag `O_NONBLOCK`, the parents file descriptor is also non-blocking, and if the parent or anything else uses the same file description and sets it to blocking, all file descriptors of that file description are blocking, in all processes using it. A `dup()` call does also not help, a call to `fcntl()` will change both file descriptors. The parent breaks when the file descriptor is non-blocking and the child breaks when the file descriptor is blocking.

I can't use `recv()` because it only works on sockets, the file descriptor can be a socket but can also be a regular file, pipe or a fifo.

I could try to change the file back to non-blocking before I exit the child, however that may not work when the child exits in a unplanned way. I can't change the parent.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: And can't you use `poll()` etc. in the child instead of relying on a non-blocking file descriptor?

Comment: It is not possible to clone an open file description. You can only create a new open file description by calling `open` and friends. I think this is by design rather than by accident.

Comment: @Shawn I would have to change a lot of code for that in multiple programs, i would rather not do that. I use `pselect()` to wait for the next event and then check every event source. I am aware of the O(n**2) of this, but it worked very well so far.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I understand that this makes sense for file offets, baud rates, ... but why for blocking vs non-blocking? You can even change this on a per syscall level with `recv()`, but this sadly does not work for pipes and regular files. A `recv()`-call that works with all file descriptor types, similar to read, would also be great.

Comment: Well there is *one* underlying file description. Not two, where one holds attributes like baid rates and the other one holds attributes like blockin status. Maintaining the two would be a PITA. That's my guess anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for cannot be done.  Things like file position and certain I/O modes, including O_NONBLOCK, are properties of the [open file description](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195164/7703) “beneath” the integer file descriptor.

Functions that newly acquire a file or file-like object (*open*, *pipe*, *socket*, etc.) allocate a new and distinct file description. However, as you’ve discovered, *dup* and *fork* and friends give you distinct descriptors which refer to a shared underlying description.